# strip() function doesn't remove trailing numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, strip

I try the following code but fails to remove the trailing digits using python 3.4.3

```
file_name = "48athens22.jpg"
result = file_name.strip("0123456789")
print (result)
```

Output:
athens22.jpg

What has gone wrong?

Comment: You have to strip the '.jpg' first.

Comment: This code does exactly what it should. It removed all the digits from the beginning and end of your string. If you want to remove all the digits from the string you should use regex or replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strip()` only strips from the end of a string; the `22` is not at the end of the string.

Here's how to do what you want:

```
import os


def strip_filename(filename):
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    root = root.strip('0123456789')
    return root + ext


print(strip_filename('48athens22.jpg'))  # athens.jpg
```

Comment: `os.path.splitext()` is the right way to work with filename extensions.

Comment: Did you mean to put that comment here? Just checking, since I _am_ using `os.path.splitext()` :).

Comment: Yeah, I meant you're the only one doing that correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

`strip` only removes from the beginning and end of the string.  Try `re.sub` instead, if you want to remove any occurrences of a substring or a pattern.

E.g.

```
re.sub('[0-9]', '', file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers *aren't trailing*. They come before the `'.jpg'`.

```
file_name = "48athens22.jpg"
name, *extension = file_name.rpartition('.')
result = name.strip("0123456789") + ''.join(extension)
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no trailing numbers , the last character in your string in 'g' , 22 is actually in the middle , if you do not want to consider the extension when striping , you will have to first split the file_name based on '.' And then strip the first part and then rejoin them.

Code -

```
filenames = file_name.split('.')

result = filenames[0].strip('0123456789') + '.' + '.'.join(filenames[1:])
print(result)
```

Comment: This prints `athensjpg`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
file_name = "48athens22.jpg1234"
result = file_name.strip("0123456789")
print(result)
```

Gives:

```
athens22.jpg
```

If you want to remove **all** digits, try:

```
import re
file_name = "48athens22.jpg1234"
result = re.sub(r'\d+', "", file_name)
print(result)
```

Gives:

```
athens.jpg
```

If you only want to remove digits before the ".", try:

```
result = re.sub(r'\d+\.', ".", file_name)
```